# what does `{}` mean as a file name in output from egrep?

Tags: grep, echo

I am on ubuntu debian 12.04, and I ran a find command to add something to all of my python files:

```
find . iname "*.py" -exec echo "import os" >> {} \;
```

The command runs without error and I want to validate the results so I egrep all of the files:

```
egrep -in "import os" *
```

And I get results looking like this:

```
{}:35:import os
{}:36:import os
{}:37:import os
{}:38:import os
{}:39:import os
```

...and the numbers go until 51 for some reason.  What does this mean?

Thank you.

Comment: You created a file named `{}` with your first command. Thus, it's a literal name.

Answer (score 2):

Your first command:

```
find . iname "*.py" -exec echo "import os" >> {} \;
```

Is looking for files ending in .py, and for each one is putting the string "import os" in a file called `{}`. Presumably there are 51 matches.

So egrep, when you run it, the `*` matches all files, including your file called `{}`. With `{}:35:import os` it's telling you that "in the file {}, at line 35, there's the string you're looking for"

Answer (score 1):

This command:

```
find . iname "*.py" -exec echo "import os" >> {} \;
```

...creates a file named `{}` (in bash, and other shells which honor redirections in positions other than head and tail -- this is an extension which the POSIX sh standard does not require). It **does not** modify the files found by `find`. (This is because the `>>` is acting as a command to the shell that's starting `find`; it's not modifying the behavior of `-exec` -- and even if it did, `-exec` directly uses `execve()` to invoke the command given; it doesn't start that command through a shell, so it doesn't honor shell constructs such as redirections, so you'd be passing literal `>>` as an argument to `echo` on any shells not implementing this extension, still not performing a redirection on the individual files found).

---

Now, if you *did* want to modify the files found by `find`, you might do so like this:

```
find . -iname '*.py' -exec sh -c 'for f; do echo "import os" >>"$f"; done' {} +
```

Noteworthy differences:

- The redirection is invoked inside a shell started with `exec sh`; thus, there's a shell present to honor it after the individual filenames have been resolved.
- `-exec ... {} +` is used, which is much more efficient than `-exec ... {} ;` (the former runs as few subcommands as possible; the latter runs one per file found).

Comment: `find . -iname '*.py' -exec sh -c 'for f; do echo "import os" >>"$f"; done' {} +` works, so thank you.  But, I don't understand how the subshell knows what `f` in the `for` loop is?

Comment: @Candic3, `"$@"` is the default thing for a `for` loop to iterate over. Thus, `for f; do` is equivalent for `for f in "$@"; do`.

Answer (score 1):

`{}` is a placeholder that is replaced by `find` with the filename that matches the given condition, in this case `{}` is replaced with filename that match the pattern `"*.py"`.

However your `find` command isn't actually doing that, as the `>> {}` is not actually part of the `-exec` block, but interpreted by the shell as a redirect for the whole `find` command, so the `{}` never gets replaced by `find` with the proper filename and instead you are redirecting into a file called `{}`. To make things more clear, the command you are actually executing is this:

```
find . iname "*.py" -exec echo "import os" \; >> {}
```

Meaning for every `*.py` file you add a line containing "import os" into a file called `{}`. The output of `grep` is just `filename:linenumber:matched_line` so you get a `{}` in there as that is the filename.

If you are wondering how the `\;` survives and why you are not getting a:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

The shell doesn't actually care where in the command line the redirect occurs:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 > foo
```

is the same as:

```
echo 1 2 > foo 3 4 5 6 7
```

and gives you this each time:

```
$ cat foo
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Also worth to mention `>>` is an append operator, so even if you fix your command you are adding to the end of the Python files, while `import os` probably should go to the top of the file.

Comment: Wow, interesting, I had no idea that the redirect could go anywhere in a command.

Comment: To be clear, that's a bash extension; the POSIX sh specification only requires redirections to be honored at the very beginning or end.